# Apache Remove Specific Query Strings

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string

I want to remove specific query strings from any URL leaving other query strings in tact, as well as account for 1st versus subsequent strings (? versus &).  I only wish to remove the following URL parameters:

campaign
external

It's important to account for the fact that these URL parameters may exist anywhere in the URL so the remaining parameters may need to be flipped to "?" from "&".

Here are a few examples:

```
Original: www.domain.com/page.html?campaign=123
Modified: www.domain.com/page.html

Orig: www.domain.com/page2.html?campaign=123&flow=shop
Mod: www.domain.com/page2.html?flow=shop

Orig: www.domain.com/page6.html?flow=account&campaign=123&entry=1&external=google
Mod: www.domain.com/page6.html?flow=shop&entry=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?:(.+?)&)?(?:external|campaign)=[^&]*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?:external|campaign)=[^&]*(?:&(.*))?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1 [L,NE,NC,R=302]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?:(.+?)&)?(?:external|campaign)=[^&]*(&.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2 [L,NE,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: Anubhava,  I need to remove the query strings from any URL, not just page.html.  I've updated the question to make that clearer.

Comment: Anubhava - I think you are taking the example too literally, I need to remove the URL parameters for **any** url - not just those with "page" in them. So page.html, help.html, pickles.php - any URL.

Comment: oh sorry it was a bad copy/paste. See my updated answer.